# [Web API Usage Rule]Name tvinputdevice is not found in the API Tizen

Tags: javascript, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I'm a beginner devoleper of Samsung Smart TV on Tizen Studio.

I downloaded this sample project: https://github.com/SamsungDForum/PlayerHTML5

I imported correctly the .wgt file in the Tizen studio but when I "check javascript rules", the console print out this error: "[Web API Usage Rule]Name tvinputdevice is not found in the API Tizen".

I have already added the privilege and the feature "tv.inputdevice".

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems only an error of the console, the project runs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the app from git repository and it runs successfully on my Web Simulator
(Samsung TV).

You may try communicating the repository owner or create an issue on the repo.